# Entity Framework method to return entities as a property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties

Hi my first question here so forgive me if its not asked in the correct manner.
I'm new to the entity framework and have a database first model.edmx file setup.
What I would like to know is if there is a way to setup a property on an entity that returns a method: 
eg.I have a Customer entity with various properties.
Using Linq I could do something like context.Customers.ToList(); to return all the customers.
How could I create a property/method that would look like this context.Customers.getAll();
I could then create others like context.Customers.getVIP(); with cetain conditions.

Comment: I was in this position once and there is little worse in the life of a new user than an anonymous and pointless down-vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a class that having all logics of an entity...

This link will help you - [Implementing Repository Pattern With Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37155/Implementing-Repository-Pattern-With-Entity-Framew)

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided above is the proper and the right way to do it. But, if for any reason you want to do it the other way, you can have a partial class for your data context

```
public partial class EntityContext
{
    public List<Plant> GetAllCusomters()
    {
        return Customers.ToList();
    }

}
```

A word of warning though, this is by no means a proper way to do it and certainly not the recommended approach.